# what is the Article List component used?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-community, kokua

We are trying to Article List Component and restricting it to an specific article type so it acts like an RSS feed. But we cannot find how to or what code to add into the specific field. Does anyone know what code you put into this field (indicated in yellow on image)

We are using to Kokua Community Template

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Article Type corresponds to an actual Knowledge Article Type, you can access these settings in Salesforce Classic under Setup>Knowledge>Knowledge Article
Types:

[image]

further details on Article types can be found [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_article_types_manage.htm&language=en&type=0) and in the [knowledge guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/208/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_knowledge_implementation_guide.pdf)

In order to filter by type, use the following syntax `{!ArticleTypeName}` Same as in the Category field.